# Use inserted value as a parameter for other inserts

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

There is a db2 database with two tables. The first one, `table1`, has autoincrement column `ID`. It is the foreign key for the `table2`.

A am writing an HTML generator for SQL queries. So with some input parameters it generates a query or multiple queries. It is not connected to the database.
What I need is to get that autoincrement field and use it in next queries. 
So basically, the scenario is:

1. insert into `table1`;
2. select autogenerated field `ID`;
3. insert into `table2` using that `ID`;
4. insert into `table2` using that `ID`;
5. ...some more similar inserts...
6. insert into `table2` using that `ID`;

And all that SQL query should be generated and then used as a single SQL script.

I was thinking about something like this:

`SELECT ID FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO Table1 (t1column1, t1column2, etc.)
                     VALUES (t1value1, t1value2, etc.))`

But I don't know, how I can write the result into a variable so I could use it in next queries like this:

`INSERT INTO Table2 (foreignKeyCol, t2column1, t2column2, etc.)
                VALUES ($ID, t2value1, t2value2, etc.)`

I could just paste that select instead of `$ID`, but the second query can be used several times with the same `$ID` and different values.

EDIT: DB2 10.5 on Linux.

Comment: You might want to mention your Db2 version and platform, as solutions might be different.

Comment: It is DB2 10.5 on Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain several inserts together using CTEs, like so:

```
WITH idcte (id) as ( 
 SELECT ID FROM FINAL TABLE (
   INSERT INTO Table1 (t1column1, t1column2, etc.)
   VALUES (t1value1, t1value2, etc.)
 )
),
ins1 (id) as (
  SELECT foreignKeyCol FROM FINAL TABLE (
    INSERT INTO Table2 (foreignKeyCol, t2column1, t2column2, etc.)
    SELECT id, t2value1, t2value2, etc.
    FROM idcte
  )
),
-- more CTEs
SELECT foreignKeyCol FROM FINAL TABLE (
    -- your last INSERT ... SELECT FROM
)
```

Essentially you will have to wrap each `INSERT` into a `SELECT FROM FINAL TABLE` for this to work.

Alternatively, you can use a global variable to keep the ID value:

```
CREATE VARIABLE myNewId INT;
SET myNewId = (SELECT ID FROM FINAL TABLE (
   INSERT INTO Table1 (t1column1, t1column2, etc.)
   VALUES (t1value1, t1value2, etc.)
));
INSERT INTO Table2 (foreignKeyCol, t2column1, t2column2, etc.)
            VALUES (myNewId, t2value1, t2value2, etc.);
DROP VARIABLE myNewId;
```

This assumes a recent version of Db2 for LUW.